# after installing Ubuntu unable to access as keyboard shift key not working so unable to enter pw

Tags: boot, keyboard, password, encryption

I have just done a fresh install of Ubuntu onto the internal hard drive of my laptop. During the process of installing Ubuntu, I clicked the option to encrypt drive, and entered the same password I used for the laptop when running Windows (it includes uppercase, lowercase , numbers, and the equals symbol, the hash symbol, and the forward slash). After the installation was complete, and the system was rebooted, now I am unable to log into Ubuntu as the Caps Lock key and the Shift key do not work (I assume they do after logging in, as I didn't experience this problem when running from the usb), and as my password contains both upper and lower case keys, it is impossible to get past the disk unlocking, never mind being able to logon!  I have Googled the problem, but after wasting hours wading through page after page that didn't resolve the problem I gave up and am hoping that a simple solution more specific to my problem may be offered.

I have a PC that runs windows, and the laptop that I installed Ubuntu on was originally running Windows with Ubuntu being run from a usb pen drive - I decided to install Ubuntu on a fresh internal drive on the laptop as Ubuntu was a bit too laggy from the usb drive...I can of course just do a fresh install without encrypting the drive...but am hoping this can be a simple problem with a simple solution.

Any help or advice will be welcomed
NB I am new to Ubuntu, and while I'm ok with navigating Windows, I am not familiar Ubuntu, that said, I enjoy learning...but patience is required, thanks

I am referring to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's the smallest change, the layout MUST be on U.S. (idk why)

So, the only way to fix it is...

Reinstall Ubuntu

Keep the layout on U.S. for now in the setup...

After decryption on first boot, you may change the keyboard layout

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct or relevant, I'm not installing to an android device, I'm installing to a laptop.

Comment: yeah lol sorry, i edited it... it actually has info that you can use.  P.S. android runs on linux @Jo-Lo

Comment: thanks for the link, unfortunately not really relating to my problem - I'm not changing keyboard layout, and during the installing process I selected the British/UK keyboard, which is what the laptop keyboard is...but the problem is that the Shift key and cap lock keys are not working - ie it is not possible to enter an uppercase letter, as Ubuntu is not enabling the keyboard properly (when I enter a letter, an astrix is entered in the password box, so Ubuntu is acknowledging the letter/key, but it is not possible to enter uppercase letters).

Comment: @Jo-Lo when logging in, on the top corner there should be a person inside a circle (accessibility button) click that and click on-screen keyboard

Comment: I'm not able to get to the login screen..I can't get past the password for unlocking the hared drive...it is just a blank mauve or purple screen with the Ubuntu logo and a message saying 'cryptsetup/; cryptsetup failed, bad password of options?'...and under there is a box for entering the password  where it says 'Unlocking the disk, Enter passphrase'.  Also it is an old PC - no on-screen keyboard - not touch-screen...if that is what you meant.

Comment: can you take a photo and upload it to imgur for me to see? @Jo-Lo

Comment: Wait! unfortunatly layout DOES matter on the encryption part!

Comment: I'd have to register for an account to upload, and can't see the point just to post a photo when a photo is not really necessary...sorry, it is the first screen that Ubuntu loads when the internal hard drive has been encrypted (by Ubuntu during the installation process).

Comment: ok... look at my new edit @Jo-Lo

Comment: ok, I'm going to try re-installing and leaving the keyboard at the default...fingers crossed....will let you know if it works

Comment: okay.. hope for the best! @Jo-Lo

Comment: @ lolreppeatlol...Sorry, I think I was getting a bit tired, so had to step away from trying to sort it out – anyhow, just an update for you and anyone who reads the post – I  managed to install Ubuntu onto the internal drive with encryption by using numericals only...it loaded with no problems after that, and all is running fine...not the most secure, but it will do until I can learn how to change the password...and just wanted to say thanks for your help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

I tried reinstalling but Ubuntu had a problem and couldn't encrypt the hard drive this time, so I thought ok, lets continue without encrypting, but kept going round in circles and wouldn't allow me to progress, so looks like the only way to resolve my problem is to wipe the drive in Windows and do a fresh install without encrypting the drive, but I'm too tired at the moment so will try later - curiously, when I rebooted into the usb/Ubuntu, I was able to access the hard drive after entering the password (via the usb loaded Ubuntu), so the problem is definitely with Ubuntu's booting/loading process..and it just seems to be getting more problematic the more I do...and I'm not familiar enough with Ubuntu to know where the problem is...or how to sort it! But thanks for your help anyway...still much appreciated